# iptables won't start and missing /proc/modules

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables

I had a perfectly working iptables but after server restart it won't start giving me
`Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle fi[FAILED]` error.
I haven't changed anything in `/etc/iptables`.

I uninstalled iptables `yum uninstall iptables` and installed it again.

Now it's even worse :( I'm getting:

```
Flushing firewall rules:                                   [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle fi[FAILED]
Unloading iptables modules: Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/modules: No such file or directory
```

How come `/proc/modules` is missing now?

I'm using CentOS 5. My iptables rules:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F OUTPUT

IPT="iptables"
ALLOWED="
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX #list of allowed IP addresses
"

$IPT -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

$IPT -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3456 -j ACCEPT

for ip in $ALLOWED
do
    $IPT -I INPUT -p tcp -s $ip -j ACCEPT
done

$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 5/s -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

First check why your /proc/modules is not available !
/proc is it mounted ? remount it if not
are you root ? on my Ubuntu, everybody can read /proc/modules.
Do you change your kernel before rebooting ? If yes, this new kernel is maybe incomplete (or doesn't support /proc, or the modules).
Do you have iptables  compiled in kernel or in modules ?

Comment: Server reboot was due to failed power socket so nothing was changed or installed prior to the reboot. I do have root access. The problem with /proc/modules only appeared when I reinstalled iptables.

Comment: /proc is mounted
mount | grep proc
/dev/proc on /proc type proc (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)

Comment: Do you have the other files in /proc ? If you type 'iptables -L -n -v' is there an answer ?

Comment: Lots of files in there

iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 72824 packets, 42M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 71056 packets, 86M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination